# Oracle 11g performance

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a performance issue on the following oracle query:

```
select tab_a.col1,tab_a.col2,tab_b.col1 etc etc from tab_a,tab_b
where 
tab_a.AS_OF = TO_DATE ('10-MAY-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
and val.PORTFOLIO_CODE IN ('91000906', '03352', '22503', '03335', '17369', '960', '04390', '02076', '52998', '02449', '02348', '17389', 'B5000', '17077', '46400',
'B6600', '53068', '52334A', '03363', '94654', 'SOFT2', 'B9000', '17137F', '03593', '04228', '04450', '17372', '52334') 
AND tab_a.NEXT_AS_AT =TO_TIMESTAMP ('12/31/9999 12:00:00.000000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM')
AND tab_a.POSITION_INTERVAL_TYPE = 'E' 
AND tab_a.POSITION_TYPE = 'T'
and tab_a.row_type = 0
AND tab_b.NEXT_AS_AT(+) = TO_TIMESTAMP ('12/31/9999 12:00:00.000000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM')
AND tab_b.AS_OF(+) <= TO_DATE ('10-MAY-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
AND tab_b.NEXT_AS_OF(+) > TO_DATE ('10-MAY-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
AND tab_b.ROW_TYPE(+) = 0
AND tab_a.SECURITY_CODE_PRIMARY = tab_b.SECURITY_CODE_PRIMARY(+)
AND tab_a.SECURITY_CODE_TYPE_PRIMARY = tab_b.SECURITY_CODE_TYPE_PRIMARY(+);
```

I realize every query behaves differenly and i will try to be as informative as possible.
But, at this point, I am looking at pointers and directions on my approach on the structure of the tables or the structure of the where clause.

Env: Oracle 11g 
Both the tables have updated stats via dbms_stats(with histograms on indexed columns: method_opt : FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE AUTO).
Tab_a : Daily range partitioned on AS_OF and hash partitioned (128) on PORTFOLIO_CODE
Tab_b : hash partitioned(128 partitions) on SECURITY_CODE_PRIMARY
Total Volume of Tab_a : 60 million(and growing)
Total Volume of Tab_b : 15 million(and growing)
Volume of Tab_a for the input as_of and the other filter conditions pertaning to tab_a: approx 6000

Tab_b has local paritioned multi column index on - SECURITY_CODE_PRIMARY, SECURITY_CODE_TYPE_PRIMARY, NEXT_AS_AT, NEXT_AS_OF, AS_OF, ROW_TYPE
Tab_A does not have any index on it as I can notice effective partition pruning already happening(partition range single for the tab_a.as_of with partition hash inlist for the tab_a.portfolio_codes) and hence do not see any value addition of creating an index which infact might be an overkill.
Expected number of output records : 6000

The below highlighted portion from the query is such that it ensures only one row is got from tab_b(we have implemented a tagging mechanism to identify records as we get intraday data at different time intervals during the day and are required to store it).
But, we are only interested in the latest time interval of the record for the SECURITY_CODE_PRIMARY and for the as_of.
So, the below portion ensures we only get one and the latest for each security_code_primary coming in from the driver table tab_a and in this case, there are about 5000 distinct security_code_primary:

```
AND tab_b.NEXT_AS_AT(+) = TO_TIMESTAMP ('12/31/9999 12:00:00.000000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM')
AND tab_b.AS_OF(+) <= TO_DATE ('10-MAY-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
AND tab_b.NEXT_AS_OF(+) > TO_DATE ('10-MAY-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
```

My question is:
Tab_a seems to be fine partition and index scheme wise.
I see a bottleneck when it is joined with a table with a structure like tab_b where we have the range (as_of and next_as_of).
I would like to get some direction on the partition scheme(and index) that we have currently in place and what may cause a performance issue.

Also, I have supplied only a partial query of a driver table joined with a secondary table.
Typically some of our queries have upto 8-10 tables just like tab_b (with exactly the same where clauses like tab_b that was highlighted) left outer joined with tab_a.

The query requires a response time in under 10 seconds while it takes around 2+ minutes today and I am trying to see what else can be done.

Comment: How about an explain plan???

Comment: tried sending it. But, it wouldn't format well and decided against it since it would be confusing. Will try again...